# File Reader only read even number line of file

Tags: java, filestream

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader br1 = null;
    try {
        br1= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("D:\\Users\\qding\\Desktop\\spy.log")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String str1;
    try {
        while((str1 = br1.readLine()) != null){
            str1 = br1.readLine();
            System.out.println(str1);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            br1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The content of file have nine lines, but the result only show the even number line content,
and the last line as null.
so why this method only reads the even number line of the file?
So strange....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use `readLine()` twice.You should modify it as follow

```
str1 =  br1.readLine();
while(str1 != null){
        System.out.println(str1);
        str1 = br1.readLine();            
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

This is because you are invoking `readLine` method twice and each invocation reads a new line from the underlying source (if it exists of course). The solution here is simply to use the `str1` variable from the `while` loop and not invoke the `readLine` for the second time.

Comment: @Shrek Ding: Sure, no worries, but it's more common to have variable assignment inside the `while` loop rather than writing it twice; once before the loop and once inside it. Also, I'll upvote your question to nullify the negative vote on it; not sure why it was down-voted by someone.

Answer (score 7):

In your code

```
while((str1 = br1.readLine()) != null){   // <= 1
    str1 = br1.readLine();                // <= 2
    System.out.println(str1);
}
```

You are reading a line two times in one loop iteration. Remove line 2 and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you read the line twice:
once in the 'while' declaration, and once inside the loop.
Remove the 'str1 = br1.readLine();' in the first line of the 'while' loop.